# Scraping facebook posts

Tags: facebook, selenium, facebook-graph-api, web-scraping

I want to scrape facebook posts with certain keywords, for example "coca-cola".
Graph api search endpoint (/search?q=coca-cola) does not work, it's returning error like

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "An unknown error has occurred.",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 1,
        "fbtrace_id": "HRj+AhMuMHw"
    }
}
```

I know, that it is also possible to scrape data with selenium using this endpoint: https://www.facebook.com/search/str/coca-cola/stories-keyword/stories-opinion, but I think browser will hang out when DOM tree will be very large. So, is there any other way to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Facebook does not allow you to scrape them. Use the API.

Comment: @WizKid What API? Graph API?

Comment: Yes that is the only API Facebook has

Comment: @WizKid But API does not allow too, /search is deprecated and there are no other alternatives

Comment: Then it is not possible

Comment: Okay, thank you then